# How to enable debug for node modules?

Tags: node.js, rename, file-rename, node-modules

Having started to work on node.js recently, I am trying to use [rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rename) package. Successfully installed (npm install rename) package and sample code (residing in file test.js) is pasted below:

```
console.log('Starting to rename');
var rename = require('rename');
rename('a.js', 'b.js');
console.log('Rename done');
```

The file a.js resides in the same directory as test.js. The console shows the two debug messages correctly, but the file a.js is not renamed.

How can I enable debug on rename module (or for that matter any node module), so that I can debug it additional log messages?

Note: Other packages like find, mkdirp, etc are working fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can enable debug by doing a **DEBUG=* node app.js** or passign env variable DEBUG with wildcard * . It would enable debug for all modules, provided the module you wish to debug is actually using debug.
Hardcore way of doing is to make local changes in the module.

Comment: Thank you Rohit, the debug works fine now.But in this case, the debug info doesn't help me much. And rename still doesn't work. Should I open a new question?

Comment: That means rename is not using debug so you would have to do it the hard way. Will try to look at rename and help out later, you may open a new question for help with rename if you wish.

Comment: Debug message are logged by using DEBUG=* node app.js. So accepting Rohit's answer